# Can you tell me the right answer in this quiz. Some people are getting confused in the translation and opting between B and C

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs

She ... as much as she says she does; otherwise, she ... so strictly all the time.

A) mustn't have earned/wouldn't have economised

B) can't earn/wouldn't have to economise

C) doesn't earn/can't have economised

D) isn't earning/doesn't have to economise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that only B is correct:

She **can't earn** *(= She is unable to be earning / it is not possible that she earns)* as much as she says she does; otherwise, she **wouldn't have to economise**[1] so strictly all the time.

[1] This use is the conditional would. She can't earn as much as she says she does; ***because if she did***, she wouldn't have to economise."

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. So comprehensive.

Comment: I agree, my answer was wrong.